# Reclaim Native resources on ending process?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, garbage-collection

When Im ending a process in the Task manager , ( kills it )

will it run its dispose or Finilize methods ?

what ends up with the native resources ?

will the operating system will clean them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispose/finalize/whatever - no.  There is nothing to run them because the OS stops, or prevents the running of, all threads of the process first.  All OS native resources linked to the process - handles. memory etc. are then all released and the process ceases to exist.

It has to be like this so that all user processes, no matter how coded or what they are doing, can be stopped.  The OS cannot be involved with finalizers etc. else user processes may become unstoppable.

Answer (score 1):

The OS will be responsible for cleaning everything. Finalize methods will no run.

You cannot expect Finalize methods to run because if your program was stuck in an infinite loop the OS wouldn't be able to kill it.

Answer (score 1):

When you terminate a process using the task manager, normal finalisation routines are not run. The process is abruptly ended. Native resources, and managed resources for that matter, are reclaimed by the OS.